# Free C++ ZIP parser with flexible license for commercial product?

Tags: c++, zip

I need to be able to parser the central directory of a ZIP file, to basically get information on the files listed in the ZIP. Currently we do this by hand through some horrible hacky code, however it would be nicer to just have an open source or free library somewhere that would let us do this.

At first I thought about using 7zip source code, however it has the LGPL license, which won't work since we'd be forced to ship the source code with our application (or, at the very least, make it available on the company website). I'd like to use a library that has a license that does not impose these kind of restrictions, if possible.

I'm using C++03 on the MSVC compiler. I have STL and Boost available to me as well, but not sure if either of those will be relevant for this.

Comment: http://www.info-zip.org source code is BSD and should give you what you need. But it's not a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you load an LGPL'd dynamic link library, you do not have to provide source code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [zlib](http://zlib.net/)?

Comment: Will ZLib let me read header/central directory information from a ZIP, and parse it out into a nice object for me? As far as I know, ZLib is only used for raw compression and doesn't handle parsing ZIP metadata. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

We've wrapped [minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html) here, it's a bit rough around the edges but it seems to work. It's under the same licence as zlib I believe.

Answer (score 0):

There is [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7530/Zip-Utils-clean-elegant-simple-C-Win32) code project source to try (I am not sure about portability though)